# I want to pass the data from second ViewController to TableView cell through protocol

Tags: ios, swift

This is my `ViewController2` from where I need to pass the data.
How do I pass the data?

```swift
protocol oppo {
    func datapass(Name:String,className:String,rollnumner:String, school:String)
}
```

```swift
class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldNames: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldClasss: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldRoll: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldSchool: UITextField!
    
    var datatrsfer:oppo!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func actionAdd(_ sender: UIButton) {
        datatrsfer.datapass(Name: txtFldNames.text!, className: txtFldClasss.text!, rollnumner: txtFldRoll.text!, school: txtFldSchool.text!)
    }
}
```

```swift
// this is main viewcontoller
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
 
    var dataArry = NSMutableArray()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        
    }

    @IBAction func actionPush(_ sender: UIButton) {
       let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc.datatrsfer = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        dataArry.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

```swift
class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell,oppo {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldName: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldClass: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldRoll: UITextField!
    
    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldScholl: UITextField!
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    func datapass(Name: String, className: String, rollnumner: String, school: String) {
        txtFldName.text = Name
        txtFldClass.text = className
        txtFldRoll.text = rollnumner
        txtFldScholl.text = school
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but never ever use a `NSMutable…` collection type for a data source in Swift.

Comment: make a debug at `func datapass(Name: String, className: String, rollnumner: String, school: String) {
    txtFldName.text = Name
    txtFldClass.text = className
    txtFldRoll.text = rollnumner
    txtFldScholl.text = school
}` If this function is called or not.

Comment: Where is the guy that you so-call 'protocal' (not my typo) defined?

Comment: `vc.datatrsfer = self` This means delegate is assigned to VC not cellVC so why are you defining protocol function in cellVC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,oppo {

```
let nam = NSMutableArray()



@IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    
    
}

@IBAction func actionPush(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
    vc.datatrsfer = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return nam.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    if let dict = nam[indexPath.row] as? NSMutableDictionary {
        cell.txtFldName.text = dict["name"] as? String
        cell.txtFldClass.text = dict["classname"] as? String
        cell.txtFldRoll.text = dict["rollnumber"] as? String
        cell.txtFldScholl.text = dict["school"] as? String
    }
    
    
    
    
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 300
}
func datapass(Name: String, className: String, rollnumner: String, school: String) {
    
    let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
    dict.setValue(Name, forKey: "name")
    dict.setValue(className, forKey: "classname")
    dict.setValue(rollnumner, forKey: "rollnumber")
    dict.setValue(school, forKey: "school")
    nam.add(dict)
    
    tblView.reloadData()
}
```

}